# Simple mysql select statement with a string

Tags: mysql, database

I have an entry in my database that has a name "ABC grocery store" and it has an id too.

```
 |_______name________|__id__|
 |ABC Grocery Store  |  ??  |
 |                   |      |
```

In my code I have the name but I need to retrive the id so I make a query:

```
 SELECT name, id FROM my_table WHERE name = "ABC Grocery Store"
```

mysql accepts the statement without errors and returns nothing. Im totally new to databases so probably an easy fix. Please help.

Comment: Why not remove `name` from your selected columns to just get ID?

Comment: It should work as you've written it. You probably have a typo somewhere.

Comment: are you sure there are no additional spaces after "ABC Grocery Store" in the database? Does it return something if you enter  `SELECT name, id FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE "ABC Grocery Store%"` ?

Comment: Are you *sure* the name is "ABC Grocery Store", no spaces before or after, correct casing, etc?

Comment: `SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE name = "ABC Grocery Store"` Doesn't work either

Comment: the select columns arent your problem. Your term may include extra characters, the entered data may contain extra characters, or your table name may be a mysql reserved word

Comment: @KaiQing If there were a reserved word problem he'd get an error.

Comment: `SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE name = "ABC Grocery Store%"` and `SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE name = "%ABC Grocery Store%"` Does nothing too

Comment: note the `LIKE` instead of `=`

Comment: MySQL ignores spaces at the end, but spaces at the beginning could cause a problem.

Comment: @barmar - right but since he didn't show more than just the query we dont know if hes getting no errors because he's suppressing or any other conditions that would prevent errors from displaying. I'm just giving crude assumptions based on the perceived level of difficulty behind a question like this

Answer (score 3):

Your row value expected may be case sensitive depending on the collation. Secondly, there might be spaces in the row values.

To only select the id, you can use:

```
SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE name = "ABC Grocery Store";
```

Otherwise, try:

```
SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE TRIM(name) = "ABC Grocery Store";
```

Or use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE "%ABC Grocery Store%";
```

Comment: Then you're selecting data that doesn't exist. Sorry!

Comment: @Acklavidian - how about `SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE UPPER(name) LIKE '%ABC%'`. If you have a row with the name you claim, this should get it regardless of collation or padding.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    SELECT  * FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE "%ABC Grocery Store%"
```

Comment: try just this if it works `SELECT  * FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE "%ABC%"`